# SQL security clarification

Tags: sql-server, security

With SQL server, do default roles 'trump' defined securables and/or custom roles?

I am cleaning up security on my servers, and I have accounts that have datareader membership to the database, membership to a custom security that grant select permissions to tables, and then there are tables from the database that are called out under Securables with select privileges to some tables.

My experience would tell me that db_datareader to the database would do the same thing.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

> With SQL server, do default roles 'trump' defined securables and/or custom roles?

Not necessarily, permissions are cumulative in SQL Server. SQL Server follows a *denied-by-default* methodology where permissions need to be given either by an explicit `GRANT` or by being added to a role that already has been granted such permissions such as the default `db_datareader` role. Explicit `DENY` always overrules any granted permissions (except the `SysAdmin` server role).

> I have accounts that have datareader membership to the database, membership to a custom security that grant select permissions to tables...My experience would tell me that db_datareader to the database would do the same thing. Am I correct?

Yes, `db_datareader` will grant access to `SELECT` from all Tables (and selectable objects, e.g. Views) from within that database. Anyone in that role and with an explicit `SELECT` granted to a particular object has redundant privileges provisioned. (It won't harm anything, but is not necessary.)

Conversely, obviously anyone who has only a few explicit Tables granted with `SELECT` won't have access to `SELECT` from any other objects. If they are added to the `db_datareader` role, then they would have access to `SELECT` from all objects (potentially more than they had before) within that database.

Comment: @PaulMcKibben Sure thing, no prob! Best of luck!